# How do I install experimental plugins for compiz?

Tags: 11.04, compiz, plugins

How to install all plugins compiz in ubuntu natty 11.04? i can't install unsupported plugins

I want to install experimental plugins, not the ones in compiz-plugins-extra. These plugins were installed by git in previous versions of compiz with a script (0.8.x):

```
atlantis 
cubemodel 
fakeargb 
tile 
snow
```

Comment: you want to install all at the same time? otherwise you can go in synaptic and install everything that contains "compiz".

Comment: I think that the new version of compiz, after the rewrite for 0.9 (11.04 came with 0.9, didn't it?), doesn't have the experimental plugins. I remember that they (or he,to be more precise) said that the new version would start by implementing the more standard ones first and then move to include the experimental ones. I might be wrong, of cource, but you should probably head to their forums to make sure that they exist before trying to install them.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu no longer supplies all of the experimental plugins. Up through Maverick you can use the [Compiz Packages PPA](https://launchpad.net/~compiz/+archive/ppa) and install the compiz-fusion-plugins-unsupported package.

What will work with Natty and Oneiric is the procedure that can be found at [UbuntuGuide](http://ubuntuguide.net/compiz-experimental-plugins-updated-with-atlantis-and-3d-cube-model). Which is to download all of the compiz plugins and rebuild them all from source. This will overwrite the plugins that are already installed via the normal Ubuntu packaging system, as well as adding the unsupported plugins.

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-bcop compiz-dev \build-essential libtool \libglu1-mesa-dev libxss-dev \libcairo2-dev git-core
git clone git://anongit.compiz.org/users/soreau/scripts
cd scripts
./compiz-addons install all
nohup compiz --replace &
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install a set of additional plugins with the package `compiz-plugins-extra`. Either install via Synaptic or `sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra`. (Make sure you have the Universe repository enabled.)

If you're talking about plugins that aren't even in the Ubuntu repositories, it probably depends on the plugin.  But I think `compiz-plugins-extra` will have most of what you want.

Comment: those I have them installed, I want to install experimental plugins, this plugins were installed by git in previous versions of compiz with a script (0.8.x)
atlantis
cubemodel
fakeargb
tile
snow

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

Check the version of your compiz (mine is 0.8.4) and download
`compiz-plugins-unsupported-0.8.4.tar.bz2` from http://releases.compiz-fusion.org/0.8.4/.

Extract and run:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo checkinstall -D
```

The `checkinstall` step creates a `.deb` package and installs it for you!

Make sure Synaptic (and Software Center, Update Manager, and any other package management utilities) is closed, so the installation can succeed.

One major advantage of this way is that you can easily uninstall it if you ever want or need to.

Comment: The link http://releases.compiz-fusion.org/0.8.4/ is broken. Can you update it?